# Is the "pass" statement neccessary/proper?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, sublimetext3

I've noticed that if I let Sublime Text 3 autocomplete my python if statements, it gives the following:

```
if :
    pass
```

My understanding of `pass` is that it won't do anything, and can be useful in a more complex loop where you want to exit on a certain condition.

`if :` won't run on its own, which leads me to think that Sublime includes `pass` in there for something other than making the code syntactically executable.

**Is there a formal reason to include `pass`, even if your code would work without it?**

Comment: `if <cond>: pass`. You have to have a condition for `if`

Comment: The code *won't* work without it if the next statement is at a different indentation level

Comment: An `if` statement requires an indented code block afterwards. Normally `pass` is just a placeholder, but sometimes you actually use it like `try:`...`except IndexError: pass`

Answer (score 2):

> `if :` won't run on its own, which leads me to think that Sublime includes pass in there for something other than making the code syntactically executable.

Yes and no. `if :` is not syntactically correct but look closely where the cursor is when you use the snippet:

[image: Cursor is between if and the colon]

So the cursor is right there where the condition goes. So the next thing that the user is expected to do is fill the condition. And as soon as there is a condition, this statement is syntactically correct and can be executed properly. It doesn’t *do* anything but it will run.

But then comes the thing about snippets: Once you have entered your condition and then pressed <kbd>Tab</kbd>, you can see that now the `pass` is selected:

[image: pass is selected]

So as you type now, you are replacing the `pass` with whatever you want to do when the condition is true. The idea here is to produce syntactically correct code as soon as possible while using the snippet functionality to give you multiple insertion points to fill in the blanks.